# Most Efficient Way Of Clearing Cache Using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, caching, cache-control

I am building an ASP.NET/Umbraco powered website which is very custom data driven via  entity framework, we are having to cache quite a lot of the data queries (For example searches by keyword) as it's a busy site.

But when a user creates a new data entry, I need to clear all the cached queries (Searches etc..) so the new entry is available in the results.

So in my create, delete and update methods I am calling the following method:

```
public static void ClearCacheItems()
{
    var enumerator = HttpContext.Current.Cache.GetEnumerator();

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(enumerator.Key.ToString());
    }
}
```

Is this really bad? I can't see how else I am supposed to clear the cached items?

Answer (score 11):

The method you use is actually the correct way to clear your cache, there is just one minor 'error' in your code. The enumerator **only is valid** as long as the original collection **remains unchanged**. So while the code might work most of the time, there might be small errors in certain situations. Best is to use the following code, which does essentially the same, but does not use the enumerator directly.

```
List<string> keys = new List<string>();
IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = Cache.GetEnumerator();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
  keys.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString());

for (int i = 0; i < keys.Count; i++)
  Cache.Remove(keys[i]);
```

Comment: Your code does not actually fix the problem of enumerating on a collection that might change.  You may have shortened the window in which it can happen, but `keys.Add` has the same problem as calling `Remove` directly, which is that the collection can change while you're enumerating.

Comment: Yes it does, neither loop changes the collection that it's using to enumerate. You first collect all keys in one collection (and make a copy of those), then use those keys to remove values from another collection.

Comment: Ahh, see I imagined the problem to be the enumeration was changing on another thread that was using the cache, and so you are still susceptible to those types of enumertaion changes.  MSDN on http cache says the class is thread safe, so it may not be an issue.  It doesn't mention specifically if the enumerator is thread safe (like it does on concurrentdictionary)

Answer (score 7):

Clearing the whole ASP.NET cache for just one specific functional domain seems a bit overkill.

You could create an intermediate object, and store all your cached queries in there. This object could be just a wrapper on a dictionary object. All queries should use this object instead of playing with the ASP.NET cache directly.

Then you add this object to the ASP.NET Cache when you need it. When you need to clear the queries, just get to this object and clear the underlying dictionary. Here is a sample implentation:

```
    public sealed class IntermediateCache<T>
    {
        private Dictionary<string, T> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, T>();

        private IntermediateCache()
        {
        }

        public static IntermediateCache<T> Current
        {
            get
            {
                string key = "IntermediateCache|" + typeof(T).FullName;
                IntermediateCache<T> current = HttpContext.Current.Cache[key] as IntermediateCache<T>;
                if (current == null)
                {
                    current = new IntermediateCache<T>();
                    HttpContext.Current.Cache[key] = current;
                }
                return current;
            }
        }

        public T Get(string key, T defaultValue)
        {
            if (key == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

            T value;
            if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
                return value;

            return defaultValue;
        }

        public void Set(string key, T value)
        {
            if (key == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

            _dictionary[key] = value;
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            _dictionary.Clear();
        }
    }
```

If my query is represented like this:

```
    public class MyQueryObject
    {
       ....
    }
```

Then, I would use the "regional" cache like this:

```
// put something in this intermediate cache
IntermediateCache<MyQueryObject>.Current.Set("myKey", myObj);

// clear this cache
IntermediateCache<MyQueryObject>.Current.Clear();
```

Answer (score 6):

It would have been very easy for the designers of the `Cache` class to add a `Clear` method to it. But they have not and it was by design - hence your code is **bad**.

One problem is **threading implications of enumerating through a collection** if the collection is modified. That would throw an error.

You really should never need to clear the whole of the cache. If server needs memory, it will clear it. Cache access is **by key** (for a reason) hence you need to know what you are trying to access. So if you need to remove and item, do it by a key.

## UPDATE

My advice would be to design the cache in a way that clearing the cache would be very easy. For example group your cache items (create a class to hold related cache results) by an ID and use the ID as the key. Whenever something related to that ID is changed, clear the cache for that ID. *Easy, peasy.*

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a **Cache Dependency**?
[Here's the MSDN explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency.aspx) and a few tidbits from there:

> Establishes a dependency relationship between an item stored in an ASP.NET application's Cache object and a file, cache key, an array of either, or another CacheDependency object. The CacheDependency class monitors the dependency relationships so that when any of them changes, the cached item will be automatically removed.

```
// Insert the cache item.
CacheDependency dep = new CacheDependency(fileName, dt);
cache.Insert("key", "value", dep);

// Check whether CacheDependency.HasChanged is true.
if (dep.HasChanged)
  Response.Write("<p>The dependency has changed.");  
else Response.Write("<p>The dependency has not changed.");
```

And [this very enthusiastic fellow](http://bencoffman.com/blog/2011/01/31/CacheInsertHttpContextCurrentCacheInsert.aspx) explains some more about it.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, never loop through the cache and remove items. It will give you a world of pain (I went through this recently). As you'll get an error "collection was modified, enumeration may not execute".

I also have a cache for searching, and I don't set an expiry - I manually invalidate when required.

The trick is the data is held into "buckets". That "bucket" is usually the parent identifier, or if you want to get into database terms, the foreign key.

So if you need to clear all "Orders" for a given "Customer", the cache key should be the CustomerId. In my case, I cache a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`. So I don't need to loop, just remove it, then add in the fresh copy.

Also, to be doubly safe - I use a **ReaderWriterLockSlim** to invalidate the cache. When I know it needs to be invalidated, I first call the database, get a write lock, flush and refresh the relevant cache, then close the write lock.

That way it's all seamless.

Comment: Interesting read on ReaderWriterLockSlim: http://kenegozi.com/blog/2010/08/15/readerwriterlockslim-vs-lock